# How to prevent anchor with query string from reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, anchor

How do I prevent anchor to reload page when there are query strings included in URL.
Below is link which reloads page before redirecting to section directly.

```
<a href="https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences/#explore">Explore Experiences</a>
```

Clicking on this link reloads page and then redirect to section (#explore). Is there anyway I can prevent reloading.

Comment: Change href="#explore" just this

Comment: If that's what you wanted I'll provide a detailed answer!

Comment: @lost_in_magento I already did this, but it still reloads page and then redirects to section. Goal here is not to reload page and go to #explore section.

Comment: It should not reload, if you were actually on that _exact_ URL (minus the fragment part) before. I am guessing you probably were not on exactly on `https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences/`, but perhaps rather something like `https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences`, without the trailing slash ...?

Comment: @CBroe I am on https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences with query strings. Link is https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences#explore which should jump to #explore section, but it reloads page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<section id="explore">
  ...
</section>
.
.
.
<div>
  <a href="#explore">The section you want to explore</a>
</div>
```

This may help you to jump to your desired section without any headache of reloading

Comment: URL has query parameters. So it reloads page before jump to desired section. 
For e.g https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences/
Check "Explore Our experiences" button on this page.

Comment: Because its an url, so it does its default behaviour(http request-response) and this will always led to reload of your page. So, its better call a section(same webpage like the one i mentioned above) using reference rather requesting a whole page again.

Comment: I do have same structure as you provided. Clicking on link appends #explore in URL and reloads the page.

Comment: As, per my previous experience #explore will get append to the original url, but while clicking it won't reload the page.

Answer (score -2):

Add a 'target' attribute to the anchor tag and write "_blank" in it, for example : target = "_blank"

in your case : `<a href="https://iamhoste.com/experiences/?in-home-chef-experiences/#explore" target="_blank">Explore Experiences</a>`

as per my knowledge this should work

Comment: target="_blank" will open page in new tab. Goal here is to redirect to #explore section without reloading page